# Rails automatic class loading at custom directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, classloader, activesupport

Rails has a feature where models, controllers, views, libraries, etc. are automatically loaded when they are needed. This is especially helpful in development mode, where they get automatically reloaded as well.

How do I tell Rails to perform automatic loading somewhere it doesn't expect to load files? Say, I create a folder `app/addons` or something, and I want it to load classes there in the same way models are loaded. So if I had `app/addons/foo.rb`, I want to be able to call the class `Foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your config/environment.rb add the following line to the Rails::Initializer.run block:

config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT/app/addons} )

Answer (score 1):

In your environment.rb should be line like this :

```
config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/ #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/addons/ )
```

Just add some another path you need.